# How can i get this background alwasys responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

Hello I make a website that create a kind of paint spatter background. i make it with jquery and css animation because the splash should grow from the center and it does not work well with jquery. I am using jquery to start the animation and removing it. Now my problem is that I give a position with % top and left but the downside is that if the site changed from height or width the location off the splash is no  longer correct does anyone have a solution so that the background always remains always fills up?
This is the webpage where i got this idee from: www.locus-solus.it/en/

Download link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B46vx3bf61vldjVRTTVXQnp4SFU

I hope I was clear enough.

EDIT:

I already use alot of media querys to fix it if you remove the media querys you can see what happen to the webpage on other divices ore put the height of the webpage to 400 you also see that it doesnt fill the full webpage.

so maybe someone know how these guys did it : http://www.locus-solus.it/en/

I load the img using a img tag.

Comment: Have you tried the css background cover or 100%?

Comment: http://www.locus-solus.it/en/  uses seperate image for mobile and desktop device using media queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `background-size: cover` for this

```
//element-selector {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

If you load image using `img` tag then you can add `max-width:100%`

```
//element-selector {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanx for you reaction. Unfortunately it does not work. maybe i do it wrong do i need to set it on my background ore on the splatter?

Comment: @Nick V, You need to add attach CSS in your element CSS, which have background image.

Comment: I load the img using a img tag.

Comment: mmm Maybe I have not explained it well. what i want is that you have a background where paint drops(the round circles) look like it fall on the background and fill the full background not with 1 circle but with more

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1
the site you gave uses a seperate images for mobile and desktop view, that is achieved using media queries, if you set your image using css background property

HTML:

```
<div class="page-header"></div>
```

CSS

```
 .page-header {
    background: url('images/normal.png');
    }

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
  .page-header {      
  background: url('images/normal-mobile.png');
  }
}
```

UPDATED Solution 2:

hiding the image based on the device width using media queries, if you set your image using html image tag(img)

```
<div class="my-class">
   <img src="image-desktop.jpg" class="hidden-phone">
   <img src="image-mobile.jpg" class="hidden-desktop">
</div>
```

here is the css to hide the based on the device width

```
.hidden-phone{
     visibility: hidden;
  }
.hidden-desktop{
      visibility: visible;
 }
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   .hidden-phone{
     visibility: visible;
    }
    .hidden-desktop{
      visibility: hidden ;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx for you answer men. but if i do this i need a lot media querys is there not another way?

Comment: For responsive design, you need to write css media queries.

Comment: do i need to set that html div page header around my full site?

Comment: I load the img using a img tag.

Comment: I have updated Solution 2, check it if it will help you.

Comment: heey can you show a example what it wil do? because i think that you think that my images are out of shape. but thats not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a responsive height for a fullbody element via css, you will only find false workaround.

But if you want, you can take the window width and window height and set them on your background via javascript!

To be more responsive as possible, you can do this on window resize too ^^

Answer (score 0):

The method that I always do in my projects is making two versions of an image .
A portrait and a landscape version . And to do that you can use photoshop and its crop and image resizing tools . And using this code ...

HTML :

```html
<div class="your-class">...</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.your-class {
  background-size: cover; /* It means 'feat to screen' */
  background-position: center; /* Center the image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Force the code to don't repeat the background image */
}

@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
  .your-class {
    background-image: url(img/background-portrait.png); /* For portrait screens */
  }
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  .your-class {
    background-image: url(img/background-landscape.png); /* For landscape screens */
  }
}
```

And for the site that you tag in your edit ...
The designer use several "div" and "img" tags and float them in page .
You can create something like that with "absolute positioning" and "z-index" .

Comment: heey can you show a example what it wil do? because i think that you think that my images are out of shape. but thats not the problem.